# How to include crypto package which is in-built into nodejs, in JMeter tests

Tags: jmeter, cryptography

We are using JMeter to execute load tests and our APIs expect an encrypted value which we have generated using crypto lib of nodejs.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use Rhino/Nashorn [`load` function](https://www.generacodice.com/en/articolo/142985/JavaScript-(Rhino)-use-library-or-include-other-scripts) like:

`load('/path/to/crypto.js')`

For example I have the following file `hello.js`

```
function hello(name) {
  return 'Hello, ' + name;  
}
```

and this is how I call it in [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)

[image]

The same way you can load any JS library of your choice

Just be aware that [starting from JMeter 3.1 you're supposed to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) as [Groovy engine provides the maximum performance](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)